# При получении данных из api с помощью Retrofit вылетает ошибка java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already executed

Tags: android, kotlin, api, retrofit, android-spinner

Пишу приложение "Курс валют". В приложении реализовано переключение между базовыми валютами, относительно которых происходит получение курса других валют. Переключение между базовыми валютами осуществляется с помощью `Spinner`. Когда я переключаюсь на новую валюту первый раз после запуска приложения, всё работает корректно, однако как только я возвращаюсь к валюте, данные для которой уже получал и выводил, вылетает ошибка:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.sem.exchangerate, PID: 9209
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already executed.
            at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.enqueue(OkHttpCall.java:123)
            at retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall.enqueue(DefaultCallAdapterFactory.java:78)
            at com.sem.exchangerate.data.dataSourceIMPL.ApiDataSourceIMPL.startMigration(ApiDataSourceIMPL.kt:25)
            at com.sem.exchangerate.data.repository.ExchangeRateRepository.startMigration(ExchangeRateRepository.kt:22)
            at com.sem.exchangerate.domain.useCase.ExchangeRateUseCase.startMigration(ExchangeRateUseCase.kt:21)
            at com.sem.exchangerate.presentation.viewModel.ExchangeRateViewModel$migration$1.invokeSuspend(ExchangeRateViewModel.kt:17)
            at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
            at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DispatchedContinuationKt.resumeCancellableWith(DispatchedContinuation.kt:367)
            at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable(Cancellable.kt:30)
            at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable$default(Cancellable.kt:25)
            at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineStart.invoke(CoroutineStart.kt:110)
            at kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractCoroutine.start(AbstractCoroutine.kt:126)
            at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.launch(Builders.common.kt:56)
            at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.launch(Unknown Source:1)
            at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.launch$default(Builders.common.kt:47)
            at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.launch$default(Unknown Source:1)
            at com.sem.exchangerate.presentation.viewModel.ExchangeRateViewModel.migration(ExchangeRateViewModel.kt:16)
            at com.sem.exchangerate.presentation.ExchangeRateFragment$onCreateView$6.onItemSelected(ExchangeRateFragment.kt:102)
            at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:957)
            at android.widget.AdapterView.dispatchOnItemSelected(AdapterView.java:946)
            at android.widget.AdapterView.access$300(AdapterView.java:55)
            at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:910)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7697)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:952)
            Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@72fd5c2, Dispatchers.Main.immediate]
```

Проблема также в том, что данные каждый раз перезаписываются, а значит их нужно заново получать (это я пишу в связи со строкой `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already executed` в тексте ошибки)

ApiDataSourceIMPL:

```
class ApiDataSourceIMPL(private val exchangeRateDataSource: ExchangeRateDataSource):
    ApiDataSource {

    companion object {
        var call: Call<ExchangeRateResponseModel>? = null
    }

    override fun startMigration (context: Context, dataApi: Call<ExchangeRateResponseModel>?) {

        call = dataApi
            // ApiClient.instance?.api?.loadExchangeRateApiUSD()
        call?.enqueue(object: Callback<ExchangeRateResponseModel> {
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<ExchangeRateResponseModel>,
                response: Response<ExchangeRateResponseModel>
            ) {

                Log.d("ApiDataSource", "onResponse status: ${response.code()}")
                // создаём список
                var loadExchangeRate: ExchangeRateResponseModel? = null
              //  loadExchangeRate?.clear()
                // получаем данные с сервера
                loadExchangeRate = (response.body() as ExchangeRateResponseModel?)!!

                exchangeRateDataSource.insert(ExchangeRateModel(1,"EUR", loadExchangeRate.rates?.EUR))
                exchangeRateDataSource.insert(ExchangeRateModel(2,"AUD", loadExchangeRate.rates?.AUD))
                exchangeRateDataSource.insert(ExchangeRateModel(3,"RUB", loadExchangeRate.rates?.RUB))
                exchangeRateDataSource.insert(ExchangeRateModel(4,"JPY", loadExchangeRate.rates?.JPY))
                exchangeRateDataSource.insert(ExchangeRateModel(5,"MDL", loadExchangeRate.rates?.MDL))

                Toast.makeText(context, "ЗАГРУЗКА", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ExchangeRateResponseModel>, t: Throwable) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "ОШИБКА! ВКЛЮЧИТЕ ИНТЕРНЕТ!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                Log.e("ApiDataSource2", "onFailure", t)
            }
        })

    }

}
```

ApiInterface:

```
interface ApiInterface {

    @Headers("apikey: мой ключ") // вставь сюда ключ с этого сайта https://apilayer.com/marketplace/exchangerates_data-api#documentation-tab
    @GET("exchangerates_data/latest?symbols=AUD%2CEUR%2CJPY%2CMDL%2CRUB&base=USD")
    fun loadExchangeRateApiUSD(): Call<ExchangeRateResponseModel>

    @Headers("apikey: мой ключ") // вставь сюда ключ с этого сайта https://apilayer.com/marketplace/exchangerates_data-api#documentation-tab
    @GET("exchangerates_data/latest?symbols=AUD%2CEUR%2CJPY%2CMDL%2CRUB&base=RON")
    fun loadExchangeRateApiRON(): Call<ExchangeRateResponseModel>

    @Headers("apikey: мой ключ") // вставь сюда ключ с этого сайта https://apilayer.com/marketplace/exchangerates_data-api#documentation-tab
    @GET("exchangerates_data/latest?symbols=AUD%2CEUR%2CJPY%2CMDL%2CRUB&base=GBP")
    fun loadExchangeRateApiGBP(): Call<ExchangeRateResponseModel>

    @Headers("apikey: мой ключ") // вставь сюда ключ с этого сайта https://apilayer.com/marketplace/exchangerates_data-api#documentation-tab
    @GET("exchangerates_data/latest?symbols=AUD%2CEUR%2CJPY%2CMDL%2CRUB&base=KZT")
    fun loadExchangeRateApiKZT(): Call<ExchangeRateResponseModel>
}
```

фрагмент ExchangeRateFragment:

```
class ExchangeRateFragment : Fragment() {

    private var binding: FragmentExchangeRateBinding? = null
    private var exchangeRateAdapter : ExchangeRateAdapter? = null
    private val exchangeRateViewModel : ExchangeRateViewModel? by viewModel()
    private val favouriteViewModel: FavouriteViewModel by viewModel()

    private val dataApi: DataApi? = DataApi()

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_exchange_rate, container, false)

        initRecyclerExchangeRate()
        loadExchangeRate()

...

        ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            activity?.applicationContext!!,
            R.array.currency_array,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
        ).also { adapter ->

            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)

            binding?.spinner?.adapter = adapter
        }

        binding?.spinner?.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
            override fun onItemSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?, p1: View?, position: Int, p3: Long) {

                when(position) {
                    0 -> {
                        exchangeRateViewModel?.migration(requireContext(), dataApi?.apiUSD)
                        loadExchangeRate()
                    }
                    1 -> {
                        exchangeRateViewModel?.migration(requireContext(), dataApi?.apiRON)
                        loadExchangeRate()
                    }
                    2 -> {
                        exchangeRateViewModel?.migration(requireContext(), dataApi?.apiGBP)
                        loadExchangeRate()
                    }
                    3 -> {
                        exchangeRateViewModel?.migration(requireContext(), dataApi?.apiKZT)
                        loadExchangeRate()
                    }
                }
            }


            override fun onNothingSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?) {

            }

        }

        return binding?.root
    }

...

    private fun loadExchangeRate(){

        exchangeRateViewModel?.loadExchange?.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {

            exchangeRateAdapter?.setList(it)
            exchangeRateAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
        })
    }
...
}
```

Comment: как вы пробовали решить данную проблему?

Comment: `Call` нельзя использовать повторно, на каждый запрос нужно получать новый экземпляр.

Comment: @Andrew, гуглил, нашёл статью с объяснением и ссылкой на документацию https://androiderrors.com/retrofit-illegalstateexception-already-executed/ но пока что не понял, как применить это в моём случае

Comment: @Andrew, попробовал через `try` `catch`, всё равно приложение вылетает и выдаёт ту же ошибку

Comment: @woesss, пока что не очень понимаю как это осуществить

Comment: Перепишите `startMigration` так, чтобы не передавать туда `Call` под видом `DataApi`, а именно `DataApi` и создавать всегда новый `Call`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы сделал это по-другому, можно универсализировать ваши API-методы в один, принимающий тег валюты аргументом, и тогда всё становится проще и короче:

```kotlin
interface ApiInterface {

    @Headers("apikey: мой ключ") // вставь сюда ключ с этого сайта https://apilayer.com/marketplace/exchangerates_data-api#documentation-tab
    @GET("exchangerates_data/latest?symbols=AUD%2CEUR%2CJPY%2CMDL%2CRUB")
    fun loadExchangeRateApi(@Query("base") String currency): Call<ExchangeRateResponseModel>
}
```

```kotlin
class ApiDataSourceIMPL(private val exchangeRateDataSource: ExchangeRateDataSource):
    ApiDataSource {

    override fun startMigration (context: Context, currency: String?) {

        val call = ApiClient.instance?.api?.loadExchangeRateApi(currency)
        call?.enqueue(object: Callback<ExchangeRateResponseModel> {
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<ExchangeRateResponseModel>,
                response: Response<ExchangeRateResponseModel>
            ) {

                Log.d("ApiDataSource", "onResponse status: ${response.code()}")
                // создаём список
                var loadExchangeRate: ExchangeRateResponseModel? = null
              //  loadExchangeRate?.clear()
                // получаем данные с сервера
                loadExchangeRate = (response.body() as ExchangeRateResponseModel?)!!

                exchangeRateDataSource.insert(ExchangeRateModel(1,"EUR", loadExchangeRate.rates?.EUR))
                exchangeRateDataSource.insert(ExchangeRateModel(2,"AUD", loadExchangeRate.rates?.AUD))
                exchangeRateDataSource.insert(ExchangeRateModel(3,"RUB", loadExchangeRate.rates?.RUB))
                exchangeRateDataSource.insert(ExchangeRateModel(4,"JPY", loadExchangeRate.rates?.JPY))
                exchangeRateDataSource.insert(ExchangeRateModel(5,"MDL", loadExchangeRate.rates?.MDL))

                Toast.makeText(context, "ЗАГРУЗКА", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ExchangeRateResponseModel>, t: Throwable) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "ОШИБКА! ВКЛЮЧИТЕ ИНТЕРНЕТ!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                Log.e("ApiDataSource2", "onFailure", t)
            }
        })

    }

}
```

```kotlin
class ExchangeRateFragment : Fragment() {

    private var binding: FragmentExchangeRateBinding? = null
    private var exchangeRateAdapter : ExchangeRateAdapter? = null
    private val exchangeRateViewModel : ExchangeRateViewModel? by viewModel()
    private val favouriteViewModel: FavouriteViewModel by viewModel()

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_exchange_rate, container, false)

        initRecyclerExchangeRate()
        loadExchangeRate()

...

        ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            activity?.applicationContext!!,
            R.array.currency_array,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
        ).also { adapter ->

            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)

            binding?.spinner?.adapter = adapter
        }

        binding?.spinner?.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
            override fun onItemSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?, p1: View?, position: Int, p3: Long) {

                val currency = when(position) {
                    0 -> "USD"
                    1 -> "RON"
                    2 -> "GBP"
                    3 -> "KZT"
                }
                exchangeRateViewModel?.migration(requireContext(), currency)
                loadExchangeRate()
            }




            override fun onNothingSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?) {

            }

        }

        return binding?.root
    }

...

    private fun loadExchangeRate(){

        exchangeRateViewModel?.loadExchange?.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {

            exchangeRateAdapter?.setList(it)
            exchangeRateAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
        })
    }
...
}
```

**P.S.** обратите внимание насколько проще теперь будет добавить ещё несколько валют, а если оформить их теги в `string-array` ресурс, тогда для этого даже не придётся править код классов, просто добавить в ресурсы имена и теги.

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо!